# Why Chrome ignores my JS source map

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, minify, uglifyjs, source-maps

I'm trying to combine my JS files using `uglifyjs`, and it's generating a sourcemap. But chrome doesn't seem to even try to load the map, and in stack traces, shows the minified file.

This is my directory with sources:

```
js-min/   ← here should go the minified files
js-src/
├── app
│   ├── dialog.js
│   ├── jslang-data.js
│   ├── jslang.js
│   ├── planner.js
│   ├── slider.js
│   ├── timed_refresh.js
│   ├── top_panel.js
│   └── utils.js
└── lib
    --snip--
```

This is a script I'm using to build a file `app.min.js`

```
# --- Output file ---
outfile="js-min/app.min.js"
outfile_map="js-min/app.min.js.map"

# --- Sources ---
src=""

src+=" js-src/app/utils.js" # contains core mods
src+=" js-src/app/timed_refresh.js"
src+=" js-src/app/jslang-data.js"
src+=" js-src/app/jslang.js"
src+=" js-src/app/dialog.js"
src+=" js-src/app/slider.js"
src+=" js-src/app/planner.js"

src+=" js-src/app/top_panel.js"

# sources variable is expanded to arguments
uglifyjs $src -o "$outfile" --compress --source-map "$outfile_map"
```

The produced sourcemap is here (shortened a bit):

```
{
    "version": 3,
    "file": "js-min/app.min.js",
    "sources": ["js-src/app/utils.js", "js-src/app/timed_refresh.js", "js-src/app/jslang-data.js", "js-src/app/jslang.js", "js-src/app/dialog.js", "js-src/app/slider.js", "js-src/app/planner.js", "js-src/app/top_panel.js"],
    "names": ["String", "prototype", "format", "formatted", "this", "arguments", "length", "isArray", "i", "replace", "pad_num", "number", "len", "padchar", "pad_char", "pad", "Array", "join", "slice", "pad2", "Function", "bind", "parent", "f", "args", "a", "temp", "apply", ....],
    "mappings": "AAIAA,OAAOC,UAAUC,OAAS,WACzB,GAAIC,WAAYC,IAEhB,...."
}
```

If you'd like to see the full file -> [gist](https://gist.github.com/MightyPork/f2748354352383dca54d)

Is there something wrong with the source map? Did I use wrong flags for `uglifyjs`?

Comment: Did you ever figure out where the problem was?

Comment: @theDminot not really, I think it was some chrome bug. It's so long ago I don't really remember if it was resolved or not